# Could a shared memory be updated in some thread while its value is still not visible to the main thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, volatile

I was reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645755%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) article about volatile fields in C#.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
class Test
{
   public static int result;   
   public static volatile bool finished;
   static void Thread2() {
      result = 143;    
      finished = true; 
   }
   static void Main() {
      finished = false;
      // Run Thread2() in a new thread
      new Thread(new ThreadStart(Thread2)).Start();
      // Wait for Thread2 to signal that it has a result by setting
      // finished to true.
      for (;;) {
         if (finished) {
            Console.WriteLine("result = {0}", result);
            return;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

As you can see, there's a loop in the main thread that waits for the volatile flag to be set in order to print 'result', which is assigned to 143 before the flag is set. It says in the explanation that if the flag was not declared as volatie then

> it would be permissible for the store
>   to result to be visible to the main
>   thread after the store to finished

Did I miss something here? Even if it was not volatile, how come the program will ever printout 0.

Comment: please don't use a busy loop!

Comment: @ David Haffernan, it's not me. it's some drunken @ microsoft

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Volatile prevents (among other things) re-ordering, so without volatile it could as an edge condition conceivably (on some hardware) write them in a different order, allowing the flag to be true even though result is 0 - for a tiny fraction of time. A much more likely scenario, though, is that without volatile the hot loop caches the flag in a register and ***never exits*** even though it has been changed.

In reality, this is not a good way to handle concurrency, and in particular a hot loop like that is really actively harmful. In most common cases, a lock or a wait-handle of some kind would be preferred. Or a Task would be ideal if you are up to date in your .NET versions.

Comment: Marc. Thanks for your response... I put Debugger.Break() just before the busy loop and injected a Thread.Sleep(2000) in the beginning of Thread2() function. I did not expect the program to break before Thread2() has finished. However, it did break before Thread2() finished. Notice in the comments it says "waits for thread2....". How's that waiting for Thread2? I understand that locks are recommended here, but I need to understand

Comment: @mustafabar it is the for loop that waits. If you break before the loop, then yes it'll break

Comment: @Marc, then I expect it to lock at if(finished).. since this is a read operation that must get the most recent value.

Comment: @mustafabar there is no reason for that to lock. It can read any value. In fact many structs could read a value that ***doesn't exist*** i.e. If the struct is larger than the atomic size for the CPU. Which is just one of the many reasons to be extremely careful with this type of thing. Honestly, you just don't write code like that so a lot of this is moot.

Comment: @Marc So for this program that uses a volatile field to behave as expected, we cannot do without a producer consumer lock for example. Even if volatile guarantees that preceding instructions are not reordered or optimization is not applied, we still have to lock and wait for 'finished' to be updated ( (s)he is using a crazy hot-loop here to do that job). Anyhow I saw it in some old code in my company, and I am sure the guy didn't know what he's doing, because it didn't really matter :)

Comment: @mustafabar pretty much; note it never locks here - just reads and loops; not quite the same.